# Запуск двух функций одновременно

Tags: python, django

У меня есть две функции. Функция `run` выполняется бесконечно. Как запустить две эти функции, чтобы и django заработал, и функция `run` работала?

```py
def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_site.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run() # Она выполняется бесконечно
    main()
```

Comment: Стоит обратить внимание на [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) или [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запускайте функции с бесконечным циклом в другом потоке.

```
th = Thread(target=run)
th.start()
```